# Preperformative concept of language

Tags: language

What is a pre-performative conception of language? Can it be explained without using philosophical terms?

Comment: Does this refer to Hamacher's conception, see [Language Pangs by Ferber, p.142](https://books.google.com/books?id=iXKfDwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)?

Comment: Do you have a specific example that brought this question to mind?

Comment: I was reading a book which discussed Gustav Stern and his theory of meaning change rooted in a preperformative concept of language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Preperformative' in this context suggests that that linguistic acts — the act of making an utterance, or of expressing a proposition — have their roots in prelinguistic cognitive states. The best example I can think of is when we forget the word for something (as we all occasionally do). We say to someone: "Hey, could you hand me the, uh... uhm... errrrr..."; then we snap our fingers or slap ourselves on the forehead and point at whatever it is until the word comes back to us. What this demonstrates is that we know the object we want and the action we want performed *before* we encode it into language, so that when there's a slip-up in that process of encoding, we *still* know what we intended even though we cannot put it into words.

This seems common sense to me, but it's a point of some contention in the philosophy of language and related fields. For instance, analytical philosophy generally disapproves of this concept, because they want to analyze language as 'fact' at the propositional level. Adding in preperformative meaning opens the door to a world of subjective interjections that they would rather not deal with.

Comment: Thank you so much Ted for your answer. Do you know any philosopher who based his/her philosophy on a pre-performative concept of language?

Comment: Eh, specifically, no. A quick Google search tells me that the direct term is sometimes used in art theory and (of all things) jurisprudence, but it does not seem to be a commonly used word. The general idea is fairly common in modern critical theory — I keep seeing associations with Judith Butler and Althusser, so anyone from that vein of thought will likely deal with it — and of course it's a concern for theoretical psychologists and language theorists, though they don't seem to use the specific term at all.

Comment: Philosophically, the concept will arise in any critique of modernism or of strict empiricism, because both modernism and empiricism depend on the *prima facia* truth of given (performed) propositions, and exposing preperformative states throws that *prima facia* assertion into disarray. But I'd have to think a bit  to dig up examples. Gadamer and Habermas could be read that way, I suppose; Gadamer would likely approve, Habermas likely wouldn't.... But take that as an off-the-cuff remark rather than an analytical claim.